# Save a .csv file to desktop

Tags: php, csv, desktop, fputcsv

I am developing a script using PHP to
save a file to desktop as .csv file.

I found this code sample from PHP Manual.

```
<?php
$list = array (
array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
array('123', '456', '789'),
array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
foreach ($list as $fields) {
fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

I created file.csv on my desktop.
My issue is I cannot find the correct path 
to open the file on the desktop and, 
write and save.  ($fp = fopen(‘file.csv’, ‘w’))

Should I have to show the path to server 
where I stored my web site and 
from there to to desk top's file.csv?

Can somebody guide me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file.csv");

// stream
$f  =   fopen('php://output', 'a');
foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($f, $fields);
}
```

Comment: Dear Amado Martinez,  Thanks for the great suggestion. It is great but, the code save all the PHP and HTML codes I wrote on the page.  Is there a way to write down only aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd
123,456,789 
"aaa","bbb" Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you very much.  With help of yours and Alain T's help I could solve the issue.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you speak about the client's desktop, you can't using this way.

Anyway, why not giving your client a way to download your file?

Update: made a small improvment from Amado Martinez's answer

```
<?php
    $list = array (
        array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
        array('123', '456', '789'),
        array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
    );

    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file.csv");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'a');
    foreach ($list as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
    fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: instead of saving to file.csv, you could stream the csv.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.  I think that should be the way.  I will check your answer and let you know.

Comment: Dear Alain T.  It works.  But there is a issue there.  After I saved the file.csv it has grab all the codes. (HTML codes I written on the template to create the page)  Is there a way to get only        aaa,   bbb, ccc, dddd     
123, 456,789
"aaa","bbb"      Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, in your current php file, add a link: `<a href="generate_csv.php">download</a>`, and in generate_csv.php, you put all your csv logic without anything else.

Comment: Dear Alain T,  Thanks for the answer.  I will try it and let you know. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save to your desktop!
Your browser runs in a sandbox, a sanitized environment that prevents access to the filesystem .

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

You script runs on server. Your file is on desktop. And even you got local server (like xamp, uniformserver etc) these are (and should be) also separated from your whole host filesystem. So the answer is - you cannot reach that unless you run your php script from command line on your host.